# What stops users from editting php variables before sending them off in POST?

Tags: php

For security reasons, I'm trying to learn more about how PHP stores variables.  PHP is a server side language, yes, but I imagine when someone is editting a php variable it stays on the local machine before being sent in POST.  So if I set a variable in my PHP code ($foo = "bar"), and want it to submit it in a later mysqli query, what stops someone from changing $foo to a different string value using some kind of external program before being later submitted?  How would I stop this if that is the case?

Comment: when you run a program, it runs as a process and a process has its memory set in the RAM. Whatever variable we declare, the variable is referenced with memory address and it can not be updated by any other process because OS gives security for that (I assume).

Answer (score 0):

You are concerning about the man-in-the-middle attack here. SSLs are meant for this and you can make encrypted `GET` and `POST` requests to prevent these risks if the data is really sensitive. Otherwise, if you are just concerning about the MySQL injections, then you will have to make your server-side code secure in order to prevent the injections.

Answer (score -1):

In order to stop someone from changing the variable you can change the variable $foo = "bar" to constant variable as ( const $foo = "bar" ). For more explanation go to the link below
http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php